# Django unit testing: How to test concurrent database operations?

Tags: python, django, unit-testing, django-models, concurrency

I'm creating a Django library which uses [optimistic concurrency control](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optimistic_concurrency_control) to prevent concurrent writes from causing inconsistent data. I'd like to be able to write unit tests for this functionality but I'm not sure how to accomplish this.

I know that Django's unit tests are single threaded, so the only way I can envision a test working is by having two separate database connections (to the same database) open simultaneously and toggling which connection the Django ORM uses when executing queries, though I'm not sure if connection toggling is even possible in Django.

What are some techniques for testing concurrent database operations with Django?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> What are some techniques for testing concurrent database operations with Django?

Actually, Django isn't an issue here.

Your library for optimistic concurrency control **must** be testable on it's own as a stand-alone unit.

Outside Django; using just unittest.

You'll need to test with multi-threaded (and multi-processing) test drivers.  Outside Django.

Once you're sure that works, you can then test  inside Django, just to be sure the API's work.

Once you're sure all of that works, you should write a simple `urllib2` test driver that executes numerous concurrent transactions against a separate Django server.  We wrote a little harness that fires up a Django server, runs the tests using `urllib2`, and then kills the Django server.

More fundamentally, you'll need some kind of pretty formal proof that your idea works.  This is far, far more important than any testing.

Comment: My library specifies an abstract model which creates queries of the form: ``update table_name set field_name = 'value', revision = (old_revision + 1) where id = record_id and revision = old_revision``. It utilizes Django's ORM. The real concurrency control is implemented on the database level via row-level locks. Unit tests will be to ensure query is properly generated and DB backend provides proper concurrency handling. Is it correct that the only way to test this is by sending concurrent requests to test server?

Comment: @shanked: "The real concurrency control is implemented on the database level via row-level locks."  Sounds like you're testing concurrency.  Right?  If so, you need to make concurrent requests to test concurrency.  I don't see any way to test concurrency without actually doing concurrency.

Answer (score 2):

Actually, testing whether a concurrent technique works is nearly impossible. It's so very easy to miss one small race-condition. The only real way is to prove your code, however, that's a lot of work ;)

Answer (score 1):

One way to handle this is to spawn multiple copies of Django runserver in separate processes pointed at the same DB. Then your unit test spawns threads/processes and they all bang on the runservers exercising your concurrency. During teardown you join with all your processes.

Answer (score -1):

use gevent:

```
import gevent

def foo():
    print('Running in foo')
    gevent.sleep(0)
    print('Explicit context switch to foo again')

def bar():
    print('Explicit context to bar')
    gevent.sleep(0)
    print('Implicit context switch back to bar')

gevent.joinall([
    gevent.spawn(foo),
    gevent.spawn(bar),
])


Running in foo
Explicit context to bar
Explicit context switch to foo again
Implicit context switch back to bar
```

http://sdiehl.github.io/gevent-tutorial/